# mongodb query array of elemnts in a field

Tags: mongodb

I have array of _id's like

```
arr=["xxxx","yyyyy",zzzz"]
```

NOw I want to return all the docs of these ids from a collection like

```
coll.find({_id:{$in:{arr}})//must return xxx.yyy.zzz docs
```

this is returning all fields from collection, How to do this?

these are my docs

```
  {_id:"xxx",
         bvalue:"val",
         cval:"val"
    }
     {_id:"yyy",
         bvalue:"val",
         cval:"val"
    }
     {_id:"zzz",
         bvalue:"val",
         cval:"val"
    }
```

I need a query which returns all documents with id's in array
In my array I have id's `xxx,yyy,zzz`
so I want all these docs to return

Comment: Re-phrase the question and give an example.

Comment: Please add your doc structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is doing exactly what it is supposed to - returning the documents that match your query criteria. If you just want the `_id`'s back, use [projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/):

```
db.coll.find({ "_id" : { "$in" : arr }, { "_id" : 1 })
```